# Updating content in contenteditable container with React

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, reactjs

I want to break the text the user inputs into the content editable container and replace the content of the container with the same text wrapped in `<span>` elements.

Here's my render method:

```
render: function() {
    var children = [],
        index = 0;

    this.state.tokens.forEach(function(token) {
        children.push(<span key={index++}>{token}</span>, <span key={index++}> </span>);
    });

    return <div 
        ref="input"
        className="input" 
        contentEditable="true" 
        onKeyPress={this.keyPress}
    >{children}</div>;
}
```

([entire example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3wkE/2/))

What happens is that after the interval (600ms) from user input, when the state changes and the component is rendered, the children are added but React for some reason adds the original text that was in the container, so it kind of duplicates the text.

Another things is that if then the user selects text and deletes it, in the next update React will throw all kind of errors such as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

and

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.$2):
>   Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly
>   mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a 
>   when using tables or nesting
>
> or  tag......

Any ideas of why this happens?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately contenteditable doesn't work properly with React-generated children right now: [Uncaught Error when using ContentEditable="true" within Chrome](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1466).

One current workaround is to build the HTML yourself or use React.renderToStaticMarkup and use React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML, though you lose some of React's benefits by doing so.

Comment: What do you mean by "build the HTML yourself"? is there a way to have a "non react child" in a react component? Also, I can't find any documentation on `renderToStaticMarkup`

Comment: Oops, looks like our docs may be lacking. `renderToStaticMarkup` is like `renderComponentToString` but doesn't include the `data-reactid` attributes (and thus event handling won't work, etc). You can also include any HTML string by doing `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "<span>...</span>"}} />`.

Comment: `renderToStaticMarkup` is briefly mentioned here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponenttostaticmarkup.

Comment: Oh yeah, and it shows up if you google it as well, just that it's `renderComponentToStaticMarkup` and not `renderToStaticMarkup` :)

Comment: Ahh, right you are. :) Probably why I didn't see it the first time I looked through the docs for it.

Comment: It's all good, I managed to work around the problem by using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Thanks for the info